# Unique items from a NSMutableArray with NSDictionary items?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary, objective-c-blocks

If you have an NSMutableArray with three NSDictionarys like this:

```
{ 
  name:steve, age:40;
  name:steve, age:23;
  name:paul, age:19
}
```

How do I turn that into an array with just two strings { steve, paul }. In other words, the unique names from the original NSMutableArray? Is there a way to do this using blocks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

something like that:

```
NSMutableSet* names = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];

[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)) {
  [names addObject:[obj valueForKey:@"name"]];
}];
```

[names allObjects] will return a NSArray of unique name

Answer (score 15):

Similar to the other answer, you could also do:

```
NSSet * names = [NSSet setWithArray:[myArray valueForKey:@"name"]];
```

Or

```
NSArray * names = [myArray valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.name"];
```

Comment: Better solution than mine ! I don't think to use valueForKey for array !